# regex search for datatable in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, regex, r-markdown, dt

[R 3.5.1, DT 0.4]

Here's some sample Rmarkdown code

````
```{r}
set.seed(100)
dt <- data.table(col1=replicate(100, paste(sample(letters,5),collapse='')),
        col2=sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE))
DT::datatable(dt, options=list(regex=TRUE)))
```
````

Based on the [docs](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/007-search.html), it seems like this should allow for regular expression searches in the table.  I would like to filter on rows for which column `col1` begins with `i`.  So, I entered `^i` in the search box and I get no rows in the output.  Do I need to set something else?

Comment: btw, you don't need `data.table` for `DT::datatable`

Comment: Agreed. I use `data.table` for all my work, and hence created the example here using the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, options is not right, should be `options=list(search=list(regex=TRUE))`

Second, `col1` doesn't sit at the start of a line, which can't be located by `^`, try `\bi` to search col1 start with `i` (`\b` locates word boundaries)

try this:

```r
set.seed(100)
dt <- data.table::data.table(col1=replicate(100, paste(sample(letters,5),collapse='')),
        col2=sample(1:10,100,replace=TRUE))
DT::datatable(dt, options=list(search=list(regex=TRUE, search = '\\bi')))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).